# Measure theory and Borel sets

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-measures

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ borelian function and $\mu$ borelian measure on $\mathbb{R}$ $\sigma$-finite

1. Given $E\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ prove that $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\in E+f(x)\}$ is a borelian set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
2. Prove that $x\to\mu(E+f(x))$ is a Borel-measurable function.

SOLUTION

1. Consider the function $\phi(x,y)=y-f(x)$, then the previous function is a Borel function because is difference of two Borel functions. Then we have that for $E\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$:
   \begin{equation}
   \phi^{-1}(E)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\phi(x,y)\in E\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y-f(x)\in E\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\in E+f(x)\}=D
   \end{equation}
   and then this last set $D\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ because the function  $\phi$ is Borel measurable.
2. Can someone help me with some hints?

Is point one correct?

Comment: Is "Borelian" different from "Borel"?

Comment: (1) seems fine. (2) is part of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem. In your case, the $x$-section of $D$ is the set $D_x = \{y : (x,y) \in D\}$, and the function you are looking at is $x \mapsto \mu(D_x)$. Any such function is measurable, provided $D$ is measurable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I think they're the same.  I've occasionally seen "Borelian" used as an adjective form of "Borel".  It might come from [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribu_bor%C3%A9lienne).